# How to redirect to the main page after fetching the auth token in Android apk?

Tags: android, android-studio

we are unable to load the feed in main page after fetching the auth token. we are trying to get the feed(articles) by sending the auth token in headers. The thing is the feed is loading the second time we open the app but not in first time. our app gets registered in db on installation and we have the login api to get the token. but the feed isn't loading simultaneously soon after we get the token. instead, it loads only after we close the app and open it again for the second time. How do we make it work to load the feed on the first access? right now we get the blank page on the first time access.

what we tried is :

In Utility. Java

```
public static void getAdId(String token,Context context) {

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AdvertisingIdClient.Info adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context);
                    String advertisingId = adInfo != null ? adInfo.getId() : null;
                    Constant.MOBILE_ADID = advertisingId;
                    Log.i("TAG9", "ADID: " + advertisingId);

                    if (!Constant.MOBILE_ADID.isEmpty() && !token.isEmpty()) {
                        if (checkInternetConnection(context))
                            sendTokenToServer(context, Constant.MOBILE_ADID, token); // App registration
                        loginDeatialsToServer(context,Constant.MOBILE_ADID); // fetches the token

                    }
                } catch (IOException | GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
```

Clientclass:

```
 builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    Context context;
                    @Override
                    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                        String token1= SharedPreference.getInstance(context).getLoginToken(context);
                        if (token1==null){
                            Utility.loginDeatialsToServer(context, Constant.MOBILE_ADID);
                        }
                        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url(apiurl)
                                .get()
                                .addHeader("Authorization",token1)
                                .build();

                        okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                        return(response);

                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The **builder** you are using will not create again, so you have to create new builder for API response, try creating **builder** again when you get token, when you close app and open again it works fine because **builder** will create again, try to print Logs, you will find your answer

Comment: Thank you for your response, we have implemented like this and it is working like your answer, but we want first time installation of app-only it has to show the main page with data.

Comment: Can you please explain issue briefly ?